# Labels mail merge repeats on subsequent pages?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge, label

I'm trying to do a mail merge to print to labels.  The first field in the document does not contain a `{ NEXT }` field code, and because of this the records repeat between label pages for example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice how the records shift to the left as the next page is displayed?  But how they start over again in an off by one manner?

Now I've tried to fix this by using the first record displayed on a page to see if the page number is 1.  If it not on page 1 of the mail merge then it should just move to the next record; otherwise it should just display the first record:

[image]

This doesn't work however, because when I do the preview and display the {page} field code, it reports that I am always on page 1 and thus the same behavior continues instead of just moving to the next record on the next page.

Comment: Viewed 30,280 times, and 2 upvotes.  Must be alot of lurkers out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh okay so it is working right...Microsoft can't make their previews work right in the Mail Merge for 2007, so here is what I did:

1. Open a Blank Word Document
2. In the ribbon bar click the `Mailings` Tab
3. Click the `Start Mail Merge` dropdown button.
4. Click `Step-By-Step Mail Merge`, the Mail Merge wizard will appear in the right hand panel.
5. Click the `Labels` radio button
6. Click the hyperlink which reads `Next: Starting document`
7. Click the radio button `Change document layout`
8. Click `Label options...`
9. Select the type of label or equivalent type of label you are using.
10. Click `OK`
11. Click the hyperlink that reads `Next: Select recipients`
12. Click the radio button `Use an existing list`
13. Click the hyperlink `Browse`
14. Find your excel file by selecting it.
15. Pick the worksheet that your mail merge data exists on.
16. Make sure all the rows of data with checkboxes next to them are rows that you want in your labels.
17. Click `OK`
18. Click the hyperlink `Next: Arrange your labels`

    1. Click the hyperlink `More items`, and in the resulting window double click the fields you need until you get to the second line of the address.
    2. Press ALT-f9
    3. From the ribbon bar click the `Insert` tab.
    4. Click the `Quick Parts` dropdown.
    5. Click `Fields...` to insert field codes.

       1. In the `Field` dialog from the `Field names:` double click `IF`
       2. `{ IF \* MERGEFORMAT }` will appear, delete the `\* MERGEFORMAT` part.
       3. With the cursor just after the `{ IF` click the `More items...` hyperlink again...
       4. Double click the field that represents the second line of the address.
       5. After the { MERGEFIELD "addr2" } is added to the `{ IF` field type `= "" ""`
       6. click the `More items...` hyperlink again...
       7. Double click the field that represents the second line of the address.
       8. Put quotes around the field you just inserted so that you have this: `{IF { MERGEFIELD "addr2"} = "" "" "{ MERGFIELD "addr2" }" }`
       9. Put your cursor between the second to last bracket and the last double quote, hold Shift+Enter.  Now when the label has a second line address it will appear and when it does not have a second line address an additional line will not appear.
    6. Add the rest of your fields using the `More items...` hyperlink (this may not be as easy as it seems depending on the size of your labels).
    7. From the ribbon click the `Mailings` tab.
    8. Click `Update Labels`, the changes will propagate to all your other labels.
    9. Press ALT+F9
    10. Click the hyperlink that reads `Next: Preview your labels`

        - Note that from here you may have to press ALT+F9, make a change, press `Update Labels` and then ALT+F9 again to get it right...it's not easy to get the spacing right.
    11. Finally when it looks right, click from the `Mailings` tab click the `Finish & Merge` dropdown button.
    12. And click `Edit Individual Document`
    13. Select the `All` radio button and click `OK`.

Comment: So in short, it's best to ignore Microsoft crappy worthless preview and take matters into your own hands, because the preview (although somewhat useful doesn't actually display the results of the mail merge in Word 2007)

Comment: I was seeing the same exact issue in Word 2013. Came here through google looking for a solution. Before going through all the steps of the accepted answer I was curious if the merge results would really match the preview? I discovered it does not need to look right before the final merge. The preview was announcing 60 pages of largely repeated labels but after merge there was only two pages.

Comment: I was following along and got lost on step 18. Nothing happens when I press
ALT-f9, I'm not sure what you mean by "double click the fields you need until you get to the second line of the address" and I don't see any drop down that says "quick parts"
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Bethany I believe ALT+F9 only works when the cursor is inside the field.

Answer (score -1):

Don't trust the Preview function! Just merge the document and it shows correctly. Preview was giving me 111 pages. Merged document was only 5 and was correctly using next records.