# Labels mail merge repeats?

Tags: email, merge

I read your response to this question ([Labels mail merge repeats on subsequent pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/482450/labels-mail-merge-repeats-on-subsequent-pages)) & I am having trouble implementing your fix. I only need to have two addresses per page (instead of a full sheet). Like the original post I too have the repeating address at the top of the subsequent page.

I didn't quite understand your response. In particular, the "addr2" field part.

My codes & address block are as follows:

((MERGEFIELD "NAME"))

or Current Resident

((MERGEFIELD "ADD FINAL"))

((MERGEFIELD "CITY")), Illinois ((MERGEFIELD "ZIP FINAL"))

Could you possibly talk me through the fix using the above codes?